# Smooth Div Scroll: как определить активный элемент и добавить класс?

Tags: jquery, slider, javascript

Здравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста. Как можно отследить блок, к которому мы прокрутили слайдер при наведении на стрелку. Как только мы докрутили до определенного слайда, добавить ему и соответствующей ссылке активный класс?

Пока что получилось только с помощью `scrollerOffset`, но событие срабатывает не сразу.

Плагин: http://smoothdivscroll.com/

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xmocartx/F5dRj/15/

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
$("div#catalog_gallary").smoothDivScroll({
    autoScrollingMode: "",
    touchScrolling: true,
    mouseOverRightHotSpot: function(eventObj, data) {
        var scrollerOffset =                    $("#catalog_gallary").smoothDivScroll("getScrollerOffset");
        if(scrollerOffset>1000)
            $('body > ul > li:nth-child(2)').addClass('active');
    }
});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте этот Сallback

```
$("#makeMeScrollable").smoothDivScroll({
    scrolledToElementId: function(eventObj, data) {
        alert("Scrolled to element id " + data["elementId"]);
    }
});
```

Comment: Да, я пробовал использовать его, но я не пойму как его правильно использовать при наведении на стрелки. По клику все получается, а по наведению почему-то не хочет, не пойму, что не так делаю..

Comment: Вот, что сейчас выходит:
http://jsfiddle.net/F5dRj/18/
Как сделать, что бы срабаталывало при наведении на стрелку?

Comment: Пересмотрев задачу, решил использовать scrollerOffset, этот Сallback тоже имеется в плагине, а наведение сделал через bind mousemove:
http://hashcode.ru/questions/306427/javascript-jqury-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B3%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE
В любом случае, большое спасибо за помощь!)

Comment: да, но если курсор держать на месте то события не будет.

Comment: Вернее без bind, просто mousemove, как не странно, но работает)
Наверно особенности работы плагина..